# Jquery map with mousewheel zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, dictionary

I'm currently putting together a map using a couple of plugins i've found. I'm building a map to sit on a page where you can click and drag. You will have the option to view the map in full screen. However what I'd like to do is add a mousewheel zoom in/out function. As click and dragging can get a little tedious.

I'm currently using a plugin which allows me to zoom in/out on the image of the map. However there are coords setup so when I click on one of the locations a pop up box appears with more information about the location.

This is where the problem comes. When i zoom in using the mousewheel the coords don't adjust with the zoom. I just to need to know if this is possible. It basically needs work like google maps. 
However being that google maps uses Geolocation i'm not sure if i can get the same effect.

plugins i'm using - http://www.jqueryrain.com/?QqcpufOA (zoom)

http://www.jscraft.net/plugins/craftmap.html (map)

If you need anymore information, let me know.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: i don't understand, Embedded Google Maps has its own scroll bind event to zoom in/out of the Map. Why are using a plugin for that?

Comment: It's a custom Image for the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a map that seems to have done what I was looking for. - http://codecanyon.net/item/rockstar-map/2004933

Great map! Allows you to view the map within the page like an Iframe and also has an option to view the map in fullscreen.